Are PostgreSQL data files only written to disk during checkpoint?
On every commit, PostgreSQL flushes WAL to disk synchronously (configurable via wal_sync_method) to guarantee durability. Data files only need to be in shared buffers, can be flushed to disk later.
My question is, on every commit, does postgres also fire a "write system call" to flush data files as well? It shouldn't impact write latency, cuz write is async, kernel only moves data from shared buffer to kernel page cache, there's no immediate IO involved.
In another word, does PostgreSQL only flush data files to disk during checkpoint, or are there other mechanisms to flush data files also?
https://youtu.be/1VWIGBQLtxo?si=ZNGu17nm2xj8JpBY&t=291
This video suggests transaction commit doesn't write data files to disk.

"...PostgreSQL flushes WAL to disk through direct IO" -- I don't see any wal_sync_method that actually uses Direct I/O.

Direct I/O is not supported by PostgreSQL. At least not in version 16 and I don't think anybody is working on that for version 17 either.

During a transaction, data are usually not written to the data files, only to WAL.
Most of the writing to data files happens during a checkpoint, but there is also the background worker that slowly writes some dirty buffers out to disk, so that there are always enough clean buffers available for client backend processes that need room in shared buffers.

yes checkpointer process flushes the pages[data files] from shared mem to disk after "checkpoint_timeout"[default:5 mins] and also bgwriter process flushes pages from shared mem to disk after "bgwriter_delay"[default:200 milli secs].
and also the processes which try to bring the pages into shared mem and could not find the "free" buffer to read the page from disk into shared mem buffer, will also try to flush pages to disk.
